# Why my second firebase take much more time than the first one?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app were I inilitialize firebase application. After that, I have a page where I load some data with some query. It looks like this:

```
  if (this.api.configs && this.api.configs.dynamic_rule) {
    console.log("inside if " + (Date.now() / 1000))
    this.unsubscribe = await this.api
      .configs
      .dynamic_rule
      .getQuery()
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        console.log("got data " + (Date.now() / 1000))
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges()
        // Checking if it's just rule activation
        if (changes.length !== 1 || changes[0].type !== "modified") {
          this.initialize(snapshot)
        }
      })
```

This query bring me just 3 simple records from the firebase.

When I get to the page for the first time, my query runs for ~300ms.

After that, every time I refresh the page, my query runs for ~4s.

I can see it by the console prints

If I run the same query directly from the browser console, it'a always running fast.

Does anybody have an idea what am I doing wrong?
(I know about cold start issue, but this is kind of warm start)

Comment: Please don't repost the same question multiple times. If you have additional information that would make your question more focused, please edit those into [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378032/why-my-second-firebase-query-is-very-slow).

Comment: That's what I did, but please unblock it